# Joined requests : OneToMany + ManyToMany

Tags: orm, symfony, entity-relationship

I'm using an analogy to make my point more understandable.
Let's imagine a library. We have Books, Collections of books, and Users.
Books, Collections and Users are my entities.

- A Collection has many Books (OnetoMany, bidirectionnal)
- A Book may have been read by several Users (ManytoMany, bidirectionnal)

I have built these relations between the three entities, and so far, it seems fine.

Question is : *how to display a list of Books for a given Collection, AND if the current User has read those Books?*

I'm starting with this request for the list of books; I don't know how to add a sub-request or something similar for the users:

```
class CollectionRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function getCollectionWithBooks($collectionName) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->leftJoin('c.books', 'b')
           ->where('c.urlname = :collectionName')
                ->setParameter('collectionName', $collectionName)
           ->addSelect('b');

        return $qb->getQuery()
           ->getSingleResult();

    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you've added a MtoM between books and users you should be able to make a method getUsers in the Books entity. This will return an arraycollection (if you declare it like so) and just do an in_array or whatever to know if your user read that book or not. (If i'm not clear or if you need an example tell me)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally, I noticed that the arraycollection and the setter were created by Symfony when I updated the entity with the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to Coussinsky.

It was finally much less complicated than I expected :)

First, we need the getter/setter of the users linked to the books.
This can be done by updating the book entity with the console, such as :

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities appLibraryBundle:Book
```

We'll have a getUsers() method returning an arrayCollection.

In the twig display, we can do something like this :

```
{% for book in collectionWithBooks.books %}
    {% if app.user in book.users %}You have read this book.{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```